# Google Ads REST API: The operation is not allowed for the given context., at operations[0]

Tags: rest, google-ads-api, google-experiments

I was trying to create a campaigBudget:mutate with all information that Google Ads API ask for, but no result, they show me only one error :

```
The operation is not allowed for the given context., at operations[0]
```

this screenshot may help you guys:

HEADER:
[image]

BODY (Req & Res):
[image]

and this is an example from Google Ads API:
[image]

Thank you

Comment: facing same issue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After research I found that the problem was CUSTOMER_ID

In header we should set : `login-customer-id => MANAGER_CUSTOMER_ID`

and in endpoint url we should set : `/customers/CUSTOMER_ID/campaignBudgets:mutate`